# Android: Open PDF File from the start every time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I have a button in my app that opens a pdf file when you press it. However when I exit the pdf file and then press the button again it opens the pdf file at the page I was last on.Is it possible to make my button open it from the start every time? How can this be done?Below is my code:

```
ImageButton userGuide = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.main_menu_user_guide_button);
        userGuide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                SimpleAudioEngine.sharedEngine(context).playEffect(
                        "sfx/Button_Pop.wav");
                File pdfFile = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/MathBarsPDFDocument/userg.pdf");
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                try {

                    startActivity(intent);

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // No application to view, ask to download one
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            HelpMenu.this);
                    builder.setTitle("No Application Found");
                    builder.setMessage("Download one from Android Market?");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, Please",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    marketIntent.setData(Uri
                                            .parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader"));
                                    startActivity(marketIntent);
                                }
                            });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("No, Thanks", null);
                    builder.create().show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make my button open it from the start every time?

No, because the behavior of the PDF viewer is up to the authors of that PDF viewer. There are many PDF viewer apps for Android, each of which can handle this however those authors want.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are sending an implicit intent. This gives android OS to decide which application should handle this. You have lost control over your the behavior of system. Now depending on behavior of pdf viewer application it works. You cant make any changes into it. If you find any action attribute then also it wont work in generic for all application. One thing that can be done is make an simple PDF viewer activity in your application.